# How to access element of a sigle row Mat in OpenCv?

Tags: opencv

I have a sigle row mat of `rows=1,cols=720`.This mat results from the reduce function in OpenCV. But when I access the element of it using `mat.at<int>(0,i)` it always assertion failed in at funciton in file mat.hpp at line 537:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] &&
        (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) &&
        CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1());
    return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0))[i1];
}
```

How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific. How did you create `mat`. What do you mean by "it fails"?

Comment: Make sure your mat's type is `CV_32SC1` and that `0 <= i < 720`. Also be sure that `sizeof(int) == 4` (if it's not, try `mat.at<int32_t>(0, i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the cv::MAT is 1 dimensional (i.e. only one of its dimensions is bigger than one) you could just do `mat.at<int>(i)`

but still the most probable cause is the mat is not type int, as @SchighSchagh suggested.