# How to access (copy) specific elements of Mat in OpenCV?

Tags: matlab, opencv

Let's say I have a matrix of single row x. In MATLAB, I can access specific elements of x via

```
x=[10 6 9 12 15 20 22];
index=[1 3 7];
y=x(index)
y =
    10     9    22
```

How can I do the same in OpenCV **(without for loop)**?

I know there are ways to access rows or columns of the matrix, but I couldn't find a way to access only specific elements in OpenCV.

Edit:

I am using C++. What if x is NxM matrix and I want to access some elements in the 5th column. In MATLAB, I can do it as x(index,5). I can sure do it with for loops in OpenCV. My question is, is there any ready OpenCV function that returns me the specific elements of x?

Comment: You can't without a `for` loop (at least in C++). What you want to do exactly? Which language?

Comment: What is wrong with a for loop?

Comment: I am using C++. What if x is NxM matrix and I want to access some elements in the 5th column. In MATLAB, I can do it as x(index,5), any comments?

Comment: `for(int i : index) { foo(x(i,4)); }`. It's quite trivial to write a small function that creates a new matrix according to a vector of indices..

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it without for loop?

Comment: Not in C++... But, really, why are you so scared about for loops?

Comment: I am not scared of for loops, just it would be very nice. For example, you can access the whole fifth column of x as  x.col(4) in opencv. I thought there would be a way to access specific elements in a specific column/row of a Mat.

Comment: Well, no. There isn't ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access element of a sigle row Mat in OpenCv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653020/how-to-access-element-of-a-sigle-row-mat-in-opencv)

Comment: @MartinBeckett  I have already said I know how to access individual elements, whole rows or whole columns in the question and in the comments. Please explain to me how it is a duplicate question?

Comment: @Ozcan If you want to access specific elements in a single row or column, you will need to use a loop.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you will have to use a loop. Unlike Matlab you can't access all the elements at once. Assuming you have a single row matrix with one channel as you indicated, the following code will work (depending on the datatype you use):

```
int foo[TheNumberOfColumnsYouNeed]; 
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.cols; i++)
{
    if(i == TheColumnsYouNeed)
        foo[i] = matrix.at<double>(0, i);
}
```

If you specifically want the 5th column of a single row matrix, you can do the following without a loop (assuming datatype double):

```
foo = matrix.at<double>(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a cv::Mat containing the values by index by using the same mechanism as cv::sortIdx  see [Sorting cv::Mat in OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831753/sorting-cvmat-in-opencv#17837910)

ie if you have a cv::Mat containing the indices you can pass this to the cv::Mat containing the data and get back that subset.